# How to compare two dictionary key values and print text in cell in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, comparison, nsmutabledictionary

I have two dictionary with multiple items. I want to compare values.

```
Dict1:{
"Displacement_trim" = "49.26 ";
"Dry_Weight" = "<null>";
}

Dict2:{
"Displacement_trim" = "171.20 ";
"Dry_Weight" = "<null>";
}
```

1. I want to know which "Displacement_trim" is greater.
2. Also checking null values.
3. Print the data in cell.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In the case that you provided, please show the output that you'd like to see when comparing those 2 dicts

Comment: @SergheiCatraniuc i am showing data in labels in that which key value is greater than i want to highlight that label.

Comment: so in your provided case, since the value of Displacement_trim in Dict2 is bigger you will highlight the label for Dict2, correct?

Comment: take out all Displacement_trim values. compare these value using NSorderascending. you will get greater values

Comment: @NarendraPandey can u explain me with some code. i tried all the ST answers but i didn't get

Comment: ok wait. i m posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out which value from the dict is bigger use the following code:

**Swift 3**

```
let dict1 = [ "Displacement_trim" : "49.26", "Dry_Weight" : "<null>" ]
let dict2 = [ "Displacement_trim" : "171.20", "Dry_Weight" : "<null>" ]

// I force unwrapped everything for brevity
if Float(dict1["Displacement_trim"]!)! > Float(dict2["Displacement_trim"]!)! {
    // highlight label for dict1
} else {
    // highlight label for dict2
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"Displacement_trim" : @"49.26", @"Dry_Weight" : @"<null>"};
NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"Displacement_trim" : @"171.20", @"Dry_Weight" : @"<null>"};

NSString *dict1DisplacementTrim = dict1[@"Displacement_trim"];
NSString *dict2DisplacementTrim = dict2[@"Displacement_trim"];

if (dict1DisplacementTrim.floatValue > dict2DisplacementTrim.floatValue) {
    // highlight label for dict1
} else {
    // highlight label for dict2
}
```

Comment: it is possible to compare these values directly with out key values "49.26 " ,  "171.20 "

Comment: we are getting "Displacement_trim" value  "49.26 " form dict1 and "Displacement_trim" value 171.20 from dict2 right? with out Displacement_trim value we can directly compare those numbers?is it possible?

Comment: `dict1DisplacementTrim.floatValue > dict2DisplacementTrim.floatValue` this does exactly that. It converts those values from strings into floats and compares them. basically this is happening `49.26 > 171.20`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1,*dict2;

 dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict1 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:13.20] forKey:@"Displacement_trim"];

[dict2 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.20] forKey:@"Displacement_trim"];

if ( [[dict1 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"] compare:[dict2 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"]]==NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"dict 2 is greater");
}else{
    NSLog(@"dict 1 is greater");
}
```

Let me know if any thing get wrong.

Comment: it's working fine. we need to change if ( [[dict1 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"] compare:[dict2 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"]]==NSOrderedAscending) to if ( [[dict1 objectForKey:@"Displacement_trim"] compare:[dict2 objectForKey:@"Displacement_trim"]]==NSOrderedAscending)

Comment: change it according your need.

Comment: it is possible to compare these values directly with out key values "49.26 " ,  "171.20 " .

Comment: if i convert that dict to array is it possible?with out valueForKey?