# How do you compare different strings in an If loop?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, comparison

How do you compare two strings with different format strings? For example, in the code below:

```
str1 = [dataDic1 objectForKey:[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
str1 contains 124.00,120/70-14,1,759,140/70-14,48.8 x 57.0.

str2 = [dataDic2 objectForKey:[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
str2 contains 1.00,90/90-6,1,250,90/90-6,45.3 x 87.0.
```

I want to compare `str1` and `str2`

```
if ([bike1Str intValue] < [bike2Str intValue]){
      NSLog(@"%@", str2);
 }
else{

 }
```

For example: `if (120/70-14 < 90/90-6)`
How do I do this type comparison ?

```
DataDic1 {
"Displacement_trim" = "124.00 ";
"Dry_Weight" = "<null>";
"Front_Brakes_Size_trim" = "260 ";
"Front_Tire_Size" = "120/70-14";
"Fuel_Capacity_trim" = "13.50 ";
"Overall_Height_trim" = "1,759 ";
"Overall_Length_trim" = "2,230 ";
Power = "";
"Power_Weight_Ratio" = "<null>";
"Rear_Brake_Size_trim" = "240 ";
"Rear_Tire_Size" = "140/70-14";
Stroke = "";
"Torque_trim" = "";
"stroke_trim" = "48.8 x 57.0 ";
}
```

and finalArray

```
(
 Power_Weight_Ratio,
 Rear_Brake_Size_trim,
 Dry_Weight,
 Torque_trim,
 stroke_trim,
 Rear_Tire_Size,
 Front_Brakes_Size_trim,
 Fuel_Capacity_trim,
 Overall_Length_trim,
 Front_Tire_Size,
 Stroke,
 Power,
 Displacement_trim,
 Overall_Height_trim
 )
```

Not only float values i am asking all the all values to compare

Comment: Try to get values in array not in string. Then its easy to compare by using for loop

Comment: @himanth. ok i will try and let u know

Comment: @himanth i tried with this code not getting plz help

Comment: Can you show your dataDic1 and finalArray?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < [bike1A count]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<[bike2A count]; j++)
        {
            if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:bike1]isEqualToString:[array2 objectAtIndex:j]])
            {
                cell.NameLbl.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:i];
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
    }

Comment: just go through it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614533/strange-problem-comparing-floats-in-objective-c. and it's not string it's float conversion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two dictionary key values and print text in cell in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506474/how-to-compare-two-dictionary-key-values-and-print-text-in-cell-in-ios)

Comment: @NarendraPandey not only float values i am asking these type of strings 120/70-14 and 48.8 x 57.0

Comment: 120/70-14 and 48.8 x 57.0 what you Call this thing float or string. why are you so confused convert this into float, store into array if it's in large amount. Sort it you will get greater or smaller value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127773/discussion-between-user558-and-narendra-pandey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1,*dict2;
NSMutableArray *ArrayContaingFloat;

dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

ArrayContaingFloat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[dict1 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:14.20] forKey:@"Displacement_trim"];

[dict2 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.20] forKey:@"Displacement_trim"];

if ( [[dict1 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"] compare:[dict2 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"]]==NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"dict 2 is greater");
}else{
    NSLog(@"dict 1 is greater");
}

if( [[dict1 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"] compare:[dict2 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"]]==NSOrderedAscending){

}

[ArrayContaingFloat addObject:[dict1 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"]];
[ArrayContaingFloat addObject:[dict2 valueForKey:@"Displacement_trim"]];

NSLog(@"Array conting float %@",ArrayContaingFloat);

NSSortDescriptor *highestToLowest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];

[ArrayContaingFloat sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:highestToLowest]];
NSLog(@"After Sorting %@",ArrayContaingFloat);
```

you will get output like this:

```
dict 2 is greater
Array conting float (
    "14.2",
    "20.2"
)
 After Sorting (
    "20.2",
    "14.2"
)
```

let me know if you have any further query.